# SQLite PUT method not working due to SequelizeUniqueConstraintError

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I built a PUT method for updating/editing inserted/existing records in sqlite db and when firing the put method the following error message is pulled up in the network tab for the PUT request. The issue seems to be related to `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError` and it auto-creating an id on update. Any thoughts or known workarounds?:

{
   "error":"An error has occured trying to create the user.",
   "err":{
      "name":"SequelizeUniqueConstraintError",
      "errors":[
         {
            "message":"id must be unique",
            "type":"unique violation",
            "path":"id",
            "value":1,
            "origin":"DB",
            "instance":{
               "id":1,
               "email":"el@gmail.com",
               "password":"$2a$08$HnRjfTzqsvwzobMQYM8bT.IkPbTSe6aOxy50l8/cUuuVhOgbl513.",
               "firstName":"el",
               "lastName":"leo",
               "jobDescription":"test",
               "gains":"100",
               "costs":"50",
               "balance":50,
               "isAdmin":null,
               "youAgree":null,
               "createdAt":"2019-03-03T09:39:31.295Z",
               "updatedAt":"2019-03-26T19:03:21.665Z"
            },
            "validatorKey":"not_unique",
            "validatorName":null,
            "validatorArgs":[

```
        ]
     }
  ],
  "fields":[  
     "id"
  ],
  "parent":{  
     "errno":19,
     "code":"SQLITE_CONSTRAINT",
     "sql":"INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`password`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`jobDescription`,`gains`,`costs`,`balance`,`isAdmin`,`youAgree`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (1,'el@gmail.com','$2a$08$HnRjfTzqsvwzobMQYM8bT.IkPbTSe6aOxy50l8/cUuuVhOgbl513.','el','leo','test','100','50',50,NULL,NULL,'2019-03-03 09:39:31.295 +00:00','2019-03-26 19:03:21.665 +00:00');"
  },
  "original":{  
     "errno":19,
     "code":"SQLITE_CONSTRAINT",
     "sql":"INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`password`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`jobDescription`,`gains`,`costs`,`balance`,`isAdmin`,`youAgree`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (1,'el@gmail.com','$2a$08$HnRjfTzqsvwzobMQYM8bT.IkPbTSe6aOxy50l8/cUuuVhOgbl513.','el','leo','test','100','50',50,NULL,NULL,'2019-03-03 09:39:31.295 +00:00','2019-03-26 19:03:21.665 +00:00');"
  },
  "sql":"INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`email`,`password`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`jobDescription`,`gains`,`costs`,`balance`,`isAdmin`,`youAgree`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (1,'el@gmail.com','$2a$08$HnRjfTzqsvwzobMQYM8bT.IkPbTSe6aOxy50l8/cUuuVhOgbl513.','el','leo','test','100','50',50,NULL,NULL,'2019-03-03 09:39:31.295 +00:00','2019-03-26 19:03:21.665 +00:00');"
```

}
}

This is the sample PUT method for reference:

```
put (user) { console.log('put user: ', JSON.stringify(user)) var userId = user.id console.log('put userId: ', userId) return Api().put(users/${user.id}, user) // return Api().put('users', userId, user) }
```

Comment: This is the sample PUT method for reference:    put (user) {
    console.log('put user: ', JSON.stringify(user))
    var userId = user.id
    console.log('put userId: ', userId)
    return Api().put(`users/${user.id}`, user)
    // return Api().put('users', userId, user)
  }